# Link doesn't reference anchor

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, anchor

I have a link that doesn't redirect to the anchor:

```
 while($nextLine != false){
                        # echo link 
                        echo '<a href="#peak1">'.$nextLine.'</a>';
                        # update line 
                        $nextLine=fgets($entireFile , filesize("Khagay Nanoproject/peaks.txt"));
                        # skip a line (for proper formatting) 
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
 echo '
                    <section>
                        <details>
                            <summary> Peak Image </summary>';
                                # create a bookmark with the id attribute. Used to link from Peak Table rows
                                echo '<h2 id="peak1">Peak 1</h2>';
```

This the order that the commands are in. Is the reason because of scope or because the anchor is after the link?

Comment: Try giving your `section` the id `peak1` instead of the `h2`.

Comment: @Lal Thanks for the reply but, it didn't work.

Comment: Are there multiple ids with peak1?

Comment: @Soundz nope, there is only one anchor that has a id of peak1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the page is not long enough. When I added a bunch of

```
<br>
```

I could see that the link and anchor were working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting element and see if id '**peak1**' exist .

It will should only scroll the page and not redirecting.

For example if I have some id a the menu bar called **top** and 
a link at the footer `<a href="top">Go top</a>`, the page will scroll top to menu bar and will not redirect.